# Use scheduler in smart contract solidity

Tags: solidity, oracles, time

I am looking for a way to automate the execution of a function.

Here is a very simple example of a function that will change the state of a boolean variable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
contract Test{
  bool public myVar = false;
  function setBool(bool setVarBool) public
  {
    myVar = setVarBool;
  }
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to automate the execution of this function, so that tomorrow for example, the state of this variable changes.
I searched on Google, I saw that it was necessary to use Oracles. However I didn't understand how to implement them.

Could someone here who has already worked with Oracle / Planners please help me?

Comment: check chainlink keepers

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on third-party services (Chainlink, Keep3rs, etc) or you can run your own bot doing it for you (using ethers or web3js with node for instance, this is basically sending a transaction when `Date.now()` satisfy some condition of yours or use `setInterval(function() { ...your tx ...}, 3600000)` for running it every 3600s)